# How do I update Kompozer through terminal

Tags: software-installation, updates

Hi I can't find anything on how to update Kompozer through terminal, I think I have an older version. Please help!

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy kompozer`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of a question about why Ubuntu doesn't have the newest version of applications, but I can't seem to find it in the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version is [kompozer (1:0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=Kompozer) in the Precise Universe repositories.

To be sure, start

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and check the version with

```
apt-cache policy kompozer
```

---

Note that Kompozer was dropped from the repositories for newer Ubuntu releases. 12.04 was the last release with Kompozer.

Comment: Thanks! And I know I had to download it through terminal because it didnt have it.